# Phonegap + Cordova + sqlite

Tags: javascript, android, apache-cordova, sqlite

Estou com um problema com um arquivo de banco mocado. Criei um arquivo .db com todas as colunas e conteudos e compilo ele junto com o apk.

A ultima alteração que fiz no banco após realizar uma nova build esta dando erro dizendo que minha tabela não existe. Já desisntalei a app e buildei novamente, limpei caches e tudo mais, mas nada resolve.

Com acesso root, acessei o pacote da app através do device e com o sqlite realizei uma query e me retornou o mesmo erro. Então fui perceber que, o arquivo do banco esta la, porém vazio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com [este artigo](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/07/27/Guest-Blog-Post-Shipping-a-populated-SQLite-DB-with-PhoneGap) isto é um problema causado pelo fato do phonegap, simplesmente ignorar seu banco pré-populado.
No mesmo link que cito acima o autor informa com detalhes maneira de contornar essa situação.
Como você verá, depois de 10hs de trabalho ele conseguiu resolver este problema.
Mas basicamente, é o seguinte que ele fez:

1. Colocou o banco populado na pasta \assets
2. Utilizou um script de terceiro pra fazer a cópia para o destino final, onde o arquivo deve ficar.

Lá tem os passos e o link do script utilizado.

Dúvidas estou à disposição.

Boa sorte.

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, fico feliz por isso!